# How to update content of the activity without creating new Activity?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity, android-xml

I'm trying to make an app and I have made a blueprint for a specific activity, but I don't know how to implement it. The layout contains few buttons at the top of the activity, and each button features some information, which is displayed inside the view. The view which needs to be updated is present under the buttons. I don't want the activity to be changed, instead it should update the contents of the View, which is different for each category/button.

By doing some research I have realised that the "Tab Layout" can be used to achieve my requirements, but I don't want the tabs and I need some stylish buttons as a replacement.

I know I'm not the best at describing, so I have looked upon Dribble and found one design which is 100% similar to blueprint.

[image: I want to achieve this Dribble design on my app]

I want to achieve this using XML and Java using Android Studio! Every suggestion will be a great support foy my app.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you could achieve that by using fragments (which is the same concept you would have used on TabLayout). I don't really know how much knowleadge you have on Android, but if you know what a Fragment is, it should be easy for you to recreate the idea.

You have 3 buttons for 3 different fragments, so you must design every fragment by separate and change it depending the button you click.

Comment: Yeah I'm a beginner. I will definitely learn about fragments and try to achieve it.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard. I'm also a beginner and fragments are one of the very first things someone learns here on Android.

Comment: Thanks bro, for the suggestion and I'm working on it <3